# Regex for String between two specific words and Broken HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is the code for scraping data from the website - http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=14

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

for num in range(14, 25):
    r = requests.get(f"http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID={num}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    names = list(dict.fromkeys([' '.join(items.split())
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'Ltd\s?$'))]))
    other = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup.findAll("strong", text=True)]))
    Name = names+other
    Address = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'Ltd\s\n\Singapore\s[0-9]{6}'))]))

    ZipCode = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'Singapore\s[0-9]{6}'))]))
    Email = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'\w*\@\.com'))]))
    Website = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'\www\.\w*\.com'))]))
    Contact = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'Contact Person:'))]))
```

Using the above code, I am unable to fetch the following two information:

- Correct & Complete name
- Address line

The HTML piece for page [second page](http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=15) for

```
Cyclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd
33 Tuas View Crescent
Singapore 637654
Tel: 6868 6000
Fax: 6863 6260
Email: tan.ey@cyclect.com.sg
Website: www.cyclect.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Marcus Tan
```

is

```
<div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;"> <br>
</span></span><span style="font-size: x-small"><span style="font-family: Arial"><span style="font-size: 10pt"><font color="#333333"><strong><a name="C"></a></strong></font></span><span style="font-size: small;"><font color="#333333"><strong>C</strong></font></span><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>yclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd<br>
</strong>33 Tuas View Crescent<br>
Singapore 637654<br>
Tel: 6868 6000<br>
Fax: 6863 6260<br>
Email: <a href="mailto:tan.ey@cyclect.com.sg"><span style="font-size: small;">tan.ey@cyclect.com.sg</span></a><br>
</span><span style="font-size: small;">Website: </span><span style="font-size: small;"><a href="http://www.cyclect.com.sg" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: small;">www.cyclect.com.sg<br>
</span></a></span></span></span><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Contact Person: Mr Marcus Tan&nbsp;<br>
<br>
</span></span><span style="font-size: small;"><strong><a name="E"></a>Engie Axima Singapore Pte Ltd</strong><br>
</span><span style="font-size: 10pt;">
<div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">108 Pasir Panjang Road</span></span></div>
<div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">#05-04 PSA Vista</span></span></div>
<div>
<div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Singapore 118535</span></span></div>
<span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Tel: 6514 1226</span><br>
Fax: 6305 9335</span><br>
<span style="font-size: small;">Email:&nbsp;</span><a href="mailto:nur-ain-binte.mohd-amin@engie.com"><span style="font-size: small;">nur-ain-binte.mohd-amin@engie.com</span></a><span style="font-size: small;"><br>
Website:&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: small;"><a href="http://www.engie-axima.fr" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: small;">www.engie-axima.fr</span></a></span></div>
</span><span style="font-size: small;">Contact Person: Mr Cedric Lucas</span></div>
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant HTML and the wanted result. (If the link breaks, or they change the structure of their HTML, then the context of your question is lost for future readers. That's why including all the information in the question itself is necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (minor formatting -- removing `&nbsp;` can be fixed later):

```
>>> a = '''<div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;"> <br>
... </span></span><span style="font-size: x-small"><span style="font-family: Arial"><span style="font-size: 10pt"><font color="#333333"><strong><a name="C"></a></strong></font></span><span style="font-size: small;"><font color="#333333"><strong>C</strong></font></span><span style="font-size: small;"><strong>yclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd<br>
... </strong>33 Tuas View Crescent<br>
... Singapore 637654<br>
... Tel: 6868 6000<br>
... Fax: 6863 6260<br>
... Email: <a href="mailto:tan.ey@cyclect.com.sg"><span style="font-size: small;">tan.ey@cyclect.com.sg</span></a><br>
... </span><span style="font-size: small;">Website: </span><span style="font-size: small;"><a href="http://www.cyclect.com.sg" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: small;">www.cyclect.com.sg<br>
... </span></a></span></span></span><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Contact Person: Mr Marcus Tan&nbsp;<br>
... <br>
... </span></span><span style="font-size: small;"><strong><a name="E"></a>Engie Axima Singapore Pte Ltd</strong><br>
... </span><span style="font-size: 10pt;">
... <div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">108 Pasir Panjang Road</span></span></div>
... <div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">#05-04 PSA Vista</span></span></div>
... <div>
... <div><span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Singapore 118535</span></span></div>
... <span style="font-size: small;"><span style="font-family: Arial;">Tel: 6514 1226</span><br>
... Fax: 6305 9335</span><br>
... <span style="font-size: small;">Email:&nbsp;</span><a href="mailto:nur-ain-binte.mohd-amin@engie.com"><span style="font-size: small;">nur-ain-binte.mohd-amin@engie.com</span></a><span style="font-size: small;"><br>
... Website:&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: small;"><a href="http://www.engie-axima.fr" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: small;">www.engie-axima.fr</span></a></span></div>
... </span><span style="font-size: small;">Contact Person: Mr Cedric Lucas</span></div>'''
>>> import re
>>> print ''.join( re.findall( r'>([^<]+)<', a) )

Cyclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd
33 Tuas View Crescent
Singapore 637654
Tel: 6868 6000
Fax: 6863 6260
Email: tan.ey@cyclect.com.sg
Website: www.cyclect.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Marcus Tan&nbsp;

Engie Axima Singapore Pte Ltd

108 Pasir Panjang Road
#05-04 PSA Vista

Singapore 118535
Tel: 6514 1226
Fax: 6305 9335
Email:&nbsp;nur-ain-binte.mohd-amin@engie.com
Website:&nbsp;www.engie-axima.fr
Contact Person: Mr Cedric Lucas
>>>
```

Comment: I tried this way. Although it prints the result , but when i run it in loop(as mentioned in original code) & assign it to a variable, it doesn't work

Comment: And also it fetches just the first page of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box Idea :)

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=14")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("span", {'style': True})[45:]:
    for lal in item.stripped_strings:
        print(lal)
```

Output:

```
ASL Shipyard Pte Ltd
19 Pandan Road
Singapore 609271
Tel: 6264 3833
Fax: 6266 1473
Email:
shipyard@aslmarine.com
shipyard@aslmarine.com
Website:
www.aslmarine.com
Website:
www.aslmarine.com
www.aslmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Ang Kok Eng
Crestsa Marine & Offshore Pte Ltd
15 Pandan Road
Singapore 609263
Tel : 6238 8881
Fax : 6278 2759
Email :
shipyard@pacificradiance.com
Website :
www.pacificradiance.com
www.pacificradiance.com
Contact Person: Mr Lau Boon Hwee
Damen Shipyards Singapore Pte Ltd
29 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638720
Tel: 6861 4180
Fax: 6861 4181
Email:
central.dssi@damen.com
Website:
www.damen.com
Contact person: Mr Michel Goedegebuure
DDW-PaxOcean Shipyard Pte Ltd
33 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638722
Tel: 6862 1188
Fax: 6861 2452
Email:
abdul.gahni@paxocean.com
abdul.gahni@paxocean.com
Website:
www.drydocks.sg
Contact Person: Mr Abdul Gahni Bin Hussain
Dundee Marine & Industrial Services Pte Ltd
14 Pioneer Sector 1
Singapore 628425
Tel: 6861 1866
Fax: 6861 1073
Email:
dundee@singnet.com.sg
Website:
www.dundee.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Tan Siam Weng
Dyna-Mac Engineering Services Pte Ltd
59 Gul Road
Singapore 629354
Tel: 6762 5816
Fax: 6762 3465
Email:
simon.teo@dyna-mac.com
Website:
www.dyna-mac.com
Contact Person: Mr Simon Teo
Five Aluminium Boat & Engineering Pte Ltd
No. 61 Tuas Ave 1
Singapore 639506
Tel: 6862 8233
Fax: 6861 0733
Email:
edmund@fiveab.com.sg
Website:
www.fiveab.com.sg
Tel: 6862 8233
Fax: 6861 0733
Email:
edmund@fiveab.com.sg
Website:
www.fiveab.com.sg
edmund@fiveab.com.sg
edmund@fiveab.com.sg
Website:
www.fiveab.com.sg
www.fiveab.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Edmund Long
Keppel FELS Ltd
50 Gul Road
Singapore 629351
Tel: 6863 7200
Fax: 6261 7719
Email:
marketing@keppelfels.com
Website:
www.keppelfels.com
marketing@keppelfels.com
marketing@keppelfels.com
Website:
www.keppelfels.com
www.keppelfels.com
Contact Person: Mr Mohamed Sahlan Bin Salleh
Keppel Offshore & Marine Ltd
50 Gul Road
Singapore 629351
Tel: 6863 7200
Fax: 6261 7719
Email:
abu.bakar@keppelsingmarine.com
abu.bakar@keppelsingmarine.com
abu.bakar@keppelsingmarine.com
Website:
www.keppelom.com
Contact Person:
Mr Abu Bakar Mohd Nor
Keppel Shipyard Ltd
51 Pioneer Sector 1
Singapore 628437
Tel: 6861 4141
Fax: 6861 7767
Email:
ks@keppelshipyard.com
Website:
www.keppelshipyard.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Albert Kee
50 Gul Road
Singapore 629351
Tel: 6863 7200
Fax: -
Email:
cheemin.yong@keppelom.com
cheemin.yong@keppelom.com
Website:
www.keppelsingmarine.com
www.keppelsingmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Yong Chee Min
Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd
48 Penjuru Road
Singapore 609152
Tel: 6777 9990
Fax: 6778 9990
Email:
thomas.tan@kimheng.com.sg
Website:
www.kimheng.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Thomas Tan
Kim Seah Boat Builders Pte Ltd
36 Tuas Basin Link
Singapore 638770
Tel: 6861 8822
Fax: 6861 1712
Email:
sales@kimseah.com.sg
Website:
www.kimseah.com.sg
Contact Person: Ms Connie Liew
Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd
15 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638709
Tel: 6861 9311
Fax: 6861 9211
Email:
louis_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
Website:
www.kwongsoon.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Louis Ching
Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd
15 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638709
Tel: 6861 9311
Fax: 6861 9211
Email:
george_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
Website:
www.kwongsoon.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr George Ching
M
MA Offshore Shipyard and Engineering Services Pte Ltd
8 Cross Street
#08-01 PWC Building
Singapore 048424
Tel: 6265 1010
Fax: 6864 5555
Email:
hr.sg@mmaoffshore.com
Website:
www.mmaoffshore.com
Contact Person: Mr Arjun Jayashankar
Pandan ShipyardáPte Ltd
3 Pandan Road
Singapore 609255
Tel: 6261 5946
Fax: 6261 5947
Email:
info@pandanshipyard.com
Website:
www.easternnavigation.com/pandan.htm
Contact Person: Mr Tan Ee Beng
Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd
48 Penjuru Road
Singapore 609152
Tel: 6777 9990
Fax: 6778 9990
Email:
thomas.tan@kimheng.com.sg
Website:
www.kimheng.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Thomas Tan
Kim Seah Boat Builders Pte Ltd
36 Tuas Basin Link
Singapore 638770
Tel: 6861 8822
Fax: 6861 1712
Email:
sales@kimseah.com.sg
Website:
www.kimseah.com.sg
Contact Person: Ms Connie Liew
sales@kimseah.com.sg
Website:
sales@kimseah.com.sg
www.kimseah.com.sg
Contact Person: Ms Connie Liew
Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd
15 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638709
Tel: 6861 9311
Fax: 6861 9211
Email:
louis_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
louis_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
Website:
www.kwongsoon.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Louis Ching
Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd
15 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638709
Tel: 6861 9311
Fax: 6861 9211
Email:
george_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
Website:
www.kwongsoon.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr George Ching
Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd
15 Tuas Crescent
Singapore 638709
Tel: 6861 9311
Fax: 6861 9211
Email:
george_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
george_ching@kwongsoon.com.sg
Website:
www.kwongsoon.com.sg
www.kwongsoon.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr George Ching
M
MA Offshore Shipyard and Engineering Services Pte Ltd
8 Cross Street
#08-01 PWC Building
Singapore 048424
Tel: 6265 1010
Fax: 6864 5555
Email:
hr.sg@mmaoffshore.com
hr.sg@mmaoffshore.com
Website:
www.mmaoffshore.com
Contact Person: Mr Arjun Jayashankar
Pandan ShipyardáPte Ltd
3 Pandan Road
Singapore 609255
Tel: 6261 5946
Fax: 6261 5947
Email:
info@pandanshipyard.com
info@pandanshipyard.com
Website:
www.easternnavigation.com/pandan.htm
www.easternnavigation.com/pandan.htm
www.easternnavigation.com/pandan.htm
Contact Person: Mr Tan Ee Beng
Penguin International Ltd
18 Tuas Basin Link
Singapore 638784
Tel : 6870 2700
Fax : 6862 1087
Email :
calvinyong@penguin.com.sg
Website:
www.penguin.com.sg
www.penguin.com.sg
Contact Person: Mr Calvin Yong
Sembcorp Marine Ltd
29 Tanjong Kling Road
Singapore 628054
Tel: 6265 1766
Fax: 6261 0738
Email:
ir@sembmarine.com
Website:
www.sembmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Chua San Lye
Sembcorp Marine Integrated Yard Pte Ltd
29 Tanjong Kling Road
Singapore 628054
Tel: 6265 1766
Fax: 6261 0738
Email:
sanlye.chua@sembmarine.com
sanlye.chua@sembmarine.com
www.sembmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Chua San Lye
Sembcorp Marine Offshore Platforms Pte Ltd
60 Admiralty Road West
#02-01
Singapore 759947
Tel: 6752 2222
Fax: 6752 8552
Email:
lokyeen.yee@sembmarine.com
lokyeen.yee@sembmarine.com
lokyeen.yee@sembmarine.com
www.sembmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Yee Lok Yeen
Sembcorp Marine Repairs & Upgrades Pte Ltd
Admiralty Road West
Singapore 759956
Tel: 6752 2222
Fax: 6758 1025
Email:
sembship.sspl@sembmarine.com
sembship.sspl@sembmarine.com
Website:
www.sembmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Simon Kuik
Sembcorp Marine Specialised Shipbuilding Pte Ltd
29 Tanjong Kling Road
Singapore 628054
Tel: 6265 1766
Fax: 6262 8274
Email:
alex.teo@sembmarine.com
Sembcorp Marine Specialised Shipbuilding Pte Ltd
29 Tanjong Kling Road
Singapore 628054
Tel: 6265 1766
Fax: 6262 8274
Email:
alex.teo@sembmarine.com
alex.teo@sembmarine.com
alex.teo@sembmarine.com
www.sembmarine.com
ST Engineering Marine Ltd
7 Benoi Road
Singapore 629882
Tel: 6861 2244
Fax: 6861 3028
Email:
stmarine@singnet.com.sg
Website:
www.stengg.com
Contact Person: Mr Phua Siang Ling
stmarine@singnet.com.sg
Website:
www.stengg.com
Contact Person: Mr Phua Siang Ling
Strategic Marine (S) Pte Ltd
51 Shipyard Road
Strategic Marine (S) Pte Ltd
51 Shipyard Road
Singapore
Singapore
Singapore
628139
Tel: 6349 8535
Fax: 6558 7277
Email:
vincyc@strategicmarine.com
628139
Tel: 6349 8535
Fax: 6558 7277
vincyc@strategicmarine.com
Website:
www.strategicmarine.com
Website:
www.strategicmarine.com
www.strategicmarine.com
Contact Person: Mr Mike Bell
Contact Person: Mr Mike Bell
YTC Shipyard Pte Ltd
39 Penjuru Lane
Singapore 609205
Tel: 6268 8888
Fax: 6268 1898
Email:
jennifer@yengtong.com
jennifer@yengtong.com
Website:
www.yengtong.com
www.yengtong.com
Contact Person: Ms Goh Yue Yu
```

Comment: Awesome !! :)
Is there a way , we can transpose the data, so that i can have Name, Address, Tel, Fax, email, Website and Contact Person as the headers in shape of a DataFrame ?

Comment: @renu you need to iterate over lines and remove duplicated lines firstly, then you will need to regex `:\n` so everything will be in one line. after that you can split based on number of lines.

Comment: I am sorry, i am not sure how to do that

Comment: @renu that's easy if you made a search

Comment: Ok, i will try that